# How to get a file from Content-Disposition in java?

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets, multipart

i am trying  to post a file form my jsp and  wnat to get on my servlet page but i ma not geting what ever code i did i mention below

**index.jsp**

```
</form>
```

**jquery :**

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/test/picctureUpload',
    method: 'POST',
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(response) {
    //  console.log(response);
        var dataString = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
        console.log(dataString.path);

    }
});
```

i have written following code in server side:

```
Part part = request.getPart("files"); // input type=file name=xxx
log.debug("Get content type==>"+part.getContentType());
log.debug("Get file name==>"+part.getName());
```

i am getting `java.lang.NullPointerException` here, how can i solve this issue?

Thanks

**form data post:**

```
-----------------------------9962829018914
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="297994_231238580266568_1872824895_n.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

Comment: share your exception stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Check the java doc here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glraq.html
You will see a detailed example of upload servlet.